# How to externalize sql statement with dynamic parameter substitution?

Tags: java, sql, spring

I'd like to provide a REST webservice for database actions. The SQL statements should be externalized in local files (not inside the code).

It would be nice to also define the parameter types inside the external files.

Normally a statement would be written as:

```
String sql = "SELECT * from user_table WHERE id=?";
PreparedStatement stm = c.prepareStatement(sql);
stm.setInt(1, 345);
//stm.setString(2, "username");
stm.executeUpdate();
```

Problem: if I'd just import the `sql statement` from file, I have to know the parameter types beforehand (and also the number of parameters). Thus have to more or less hardcode the statement fetching.

But I'd like to be able to replace the sql statement at runtime (and eg add or remove parameters) without having to touch the java code. So I could change the sql without having to restart the service.

Like (pseudocode):

```
<definition>
  <sql id="getUsers">
     <statement>SELECT * from user_table WHERE id=? and name=?</statement>
     <param idx="1" type="Integer"/>
     <param idx="2" type="String"/>
  </sql>
</definition>
```

And then just feed the sql statement with parameters from a Map.

Question: is there any existing framework that provides such a mechanism for templating the sql in external files. And feed the sql statements with parameters from a `HashMap` (that might eg be received via `POST` dynamically from a webservice)?

Sidenote: the sql in the file must be native sql. I cannot make use of eg HSQL or similar.
Sidenote2: I'm not looking for an ORM, I know there is hibernate to map between database and java beans. But I'm not interested in mapping the sql result to beans. My focus is to have the ability to interchange the sql statements dynamically without having to recompile.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am following you.  It seems like you are talking about ORM.  Especially if your question is " is there any existing framework that provides such a mechanism for templating the sql in external files. ".  But beforehand when you were talking about parameter types made it sound like something different. Please clarify

Comment: Well, I'd like to put the sql in an external file, eg an xml file. The sql statement inside that file should be changeable during runtime, so that I could execute a modified sql without having to redeploy or restart. The parameters that are to be feed into the sql come from a JSON POST request. And thus should be dynamically set into that sql (read from xml file). So I could introduce an additional `where name=?`, provide an additional parameter via the webservice, and then can directly run the sql.

Comment: NamedParameterSJDBCTemplate? http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/using-namedparameterjdbctemplate-in.html

Comment: No. In the example you see that they use explicit types for the `SELECT *` statements, eg `Integer.valueOf(empid)`. My intention is to be independent of types, as otherwise I cannot change the sql statements during runtime.